# Customized Vertical Menu

Tags: 7, routes

I am little bit familiar with Drupal but have no idea how to approach this problem. I want to create a menu in the following style with straight continuous lines for each tab.

```
                  ----- sub1
                 |
    tab1---------|----- sub2
                 |
                  ----- sub3
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

use the super fish module. http://www.drupal.org/project/superfish that should do what you need.

Comment: Thanks ducks for your reply, I am using superfish in one of my site but my problem is how to draw these line not complete box, what I mean is when I hover on a tab with extended links it opens another level of tabs in a dropdown or slideout menu in a box. I can use css to display only text but the problem is the line structure. how to draw it?

Comment: since its custom. you'll have to program it via js.